# Error creating transaction manager bean

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hi Im creating a sample project for springMVc with hibernate with oracle as backend . I am stuck with one issue seems like some configuration issue but unable to identify whats wrong. Any guidance will be of great help.

```
org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
```

The stacktrace:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getTransactionManager' defined in common.configuaration.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
Apr 05, 2018 5:42:38 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID]
Apr 05, 2018 5:42:38 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getTransactionManager' defined in common.configuaration.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4577)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5041)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.unwrap(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:217)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(SessionFactoryUtils.java:198)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
```

find below my hibernate config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "common.spring.service")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "common.spring.dao")
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
       public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
          LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

          Properties props = new Properties();
          // Setting JDBC properties
          props.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          props.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID");
          props.put("hibernate.connection.username", "test");
          props.put("hibernate.connection.password", "test123");
          props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
          //props.put("hibernate.default_schema", "CCTRL1D");

          // Setting Hibernate properties
          props.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
         // props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

//        // Setting C3P0 properties
          props.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size","5");
          props.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size","20");
          props.put("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment","1");
          props.put("hibernate.c3p0.timeout","1000");
          props.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements","150");

          factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
          factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("common.spring.model");

          return factoryBean;
       }

    @Bean
       public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
          HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
          transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
          return transactionManager;
       }    

}
```

I am using below version of spring and hibernate

```
<springframework.version>4.3.10.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.11.Final</hibernate.version>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error

> org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to
>   requested type [javax.sql.DataSource

is pretty much self describing: Spring is the one to configure and set your database layer for you. For that it needs to have from you a javax.sql.DataSource already configured. You, instead are giving it through a group of properties values which are unusable.

try to modify  AppConfig like this:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "common.spring.service")
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "common.spring.dao")
    public class AppConfig {
        @Bean
           public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
              LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

              Properties props = new Properties();
              // Setting JDBC properties
             // props.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            //  props.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:SID");
              //props.put("hibernate.connection.username", "test");
              //props.put("hibernate.connection.password", "test123");
              props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
              //props.put("hibernate.default_schema", "CCTRL1D");

              // Setting Hibernate properties
              props.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
             // props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

    //        // Setting C3P0 properties
              props.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size","5");
              props.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size","20");
              props.put("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment","1");
              props.put("hibernate.c3p0.timeout","1000");
              props.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements","150");

              factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
              factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("common.spring.model");

              return factoryBean;
           }

        @Bean
           public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
              HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
              transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
              return transactionManager;
           }

@Bean
public static DataSource getDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("yourDriverClasName");
    dataSource.setUrl("yourDbUrl");
    dataSource.setUsername("yourDbUser");
    dataSource.setPassword("yourDbPassowrd");
    return dataSource;
}    

    }
```

Comment: BasicDatasource is not getting resolved for hibernate+ oracle what is the corresponding class?

Comment: BasicDatasource is from the common-dbcp artifact, that you can get with maven: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>