# Spring 5, Hibernate 5, Postgresql - error "Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]"

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I am learing Spring 5. I have converted [Spring 5 MVC + Hibernate 5 Example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/spring5-mvc-hibernate5-example/) tutorial from HSQL to PostgreSQL one, but it has not worked. The error is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getTransactionManager' defined in com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.config.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
```

How to fix it?

Here you are files of the project and bigger error message:

*./pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.howtodoinjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-webmvc Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <spring.version>5.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator>5.4.1.Final</hibernate.validator>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.5.2</c3p0.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2.1</jstl.version>
        <tld.version>1.1.2</tld.version>
        <servlets.version>3.1.0</servlets.version>
        <jsp.version>2.3.1</jsp.version>
        <hsqldb.version>1.8.0.10</hsqldb.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring MVC Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate-C3P0 Integration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- c3p0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>${tld.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlets.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HSQL Dependency -->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- POSTGRESQL Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Embedded Apache Tomcat required for testing war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

*./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/editUsers.jsp*

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Spring5 MVC Hibernate Demo</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .error {
                color: red;
            }
            table {
                width: 50%;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0px;
            }
            table td {
                border: 1px solid #565454;
                padding: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Input Form</h1>
        <form:form action="addUser" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="name" /> <br />
                        <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="email" /> <br />
                        <form:errors path="email" cssClass="error" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form:form>
        
        <h2>Users List</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
                <tr>
                    <td>${user.name}</td>
                    <td>${user.email}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

*./src/main/java/com/howtodoinjava/demo/spring/service/UserService.java*

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.model.User;

public interface UserService {
   void save(User user);

   List<User> list();
}
```

*./src/main/java/com/howtodoinjava/demo/spring/service/UserServiceImp.java*

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.dao.UserDao;
import com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.model.User;

@Service
public class UserServiceImp implements UserService {

   @Autowired
   private UserDao userDao;

   @Transactional
   public void save(User user) {
      userDao.save(user);
   }

   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   public List<User> list() {
      return userDao.list();
   }

}
```

*./src/main/java/com/howtodoinjava/demo/spring/controller/UserController.java*

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.controller;

import java.util.Locale;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.model.User;
import com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String userForm(Locale locale, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.list());
        return "editUsers";
    }
    
    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User formBackingObject() {
        return new User();
    }

    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("users", userService.list());
            return "editUsers";
        }

        userService.save(user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

*./src/main/java/com/howtodoinjava/demo/spring/dao/UserDaoImp.java*

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.model.User;

@Repository
public class UserDaoImp implements UserDao {

   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   @Override
   public void save(User user) {
      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(user);
   }

   @Override
   public List<User> list() {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      TypedQuery<User> query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User");
      return query.getResultList();
   }

}
```

*./src/main/java/com/howtodoinjava/demo/spring/dao/UserDao.java*

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.model.User;

public interface UserDao {
   void save(User user);
   List<User> list();
}
```

*./src/main/java/com/howtodoinjava/demo/spring/config/WebMvcConfig.java*

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.config;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring"})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

   @Bean
   public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
      InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
      resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
      resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return resolver;
   }

   @Bean
   public MessageSource messageSource() {
      ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
      source.setBasename("messages");
      return source;
   }

   @Override
   public Validator getValidator() {
      LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
      validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
      return validator;
   }
}
```

*./src/main/java/com/howtodoinjava/demo/spring/config/HibernateConfig.java*

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScans;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.model.User;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScans(value = { @ComponentScan("com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring")})
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setConfigLocation(context.getResource("classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"));
        factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

*./src/main/java/com/howtodoinjava/demo/spring/config/AppInitializer.java*

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { HibernateConfig.class };
   }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { WebMvcConfig.class };
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
   }
}
```

*./src/main/java/com/howtodoinjava/demo/spring/model/User.java*

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;


@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_USERS")
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "USER_ID")
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
   @Size(max = 20, min = 3, message = "{user.name.invalid}")
   @NotEmpty(message="Please Enter your name")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "USER_EMAIL", unique = true)
   @Email(message = "{user.email.invalid}")
   @NotEmpty(message="Please Enter your email")
   private String email;

   public Long getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(Long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getEmail() {
      return email;
   }

   public void setEmail(String email) {
      this.email = email;
   }
}
```

*./src/main/resources/messages.properties*

```
user.name.invalid = Name entered is invalid. It must be between {3} and {20} characters.
user.email.invalid = Invalid email! Please enter valid email.
```

*./src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml*

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example</property> <!-- BD Mane -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property> <!-- DB Driver -->
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property> <!-- DB User -->
        <property name="connection.password">postgres</property> <!-- DB Password -->

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property> <!-- DB Dialect -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> <!-- create / create-drop / update -->

        <property name="show_sql">true</property> <!-- Show SQL in console -->
        <property name="format_sql">true</property> <!-- Show SQL formatted -->

        <mapping class="com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.model.User"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Error message:

```
(...)
21-Aug-2020 12:50:00.346 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry.register HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@fb3f21e
21-Aug-2020 12:50:00.755 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.<clinit> HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.4.1.Final
21-Aug-2020 12:50:01.018 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@6c19d143] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
21-Aug-2020 12:50:01.311 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getTransactionManager' defined in com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.config.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
21-Aug-2020 12:50:01.311 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.stop HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example]
21-Aug-2020 12:50:01.315 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getTransactionManager' defined in com.howtodoinjava.demo.spring.config.HibernateConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4676)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5139)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1727)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.unwrap(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:217)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(SessionFactoryUtils.java:205)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:382)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1862)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799)
        ... 59 more
21-Aug-2020 12:50:01.316 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
21-Aug-2020 12:50:01.318 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
21-Aug-2020 12:50:01.325 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2020-08-21 12:50:01,339] Artifact hibernate:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
21-Aug-2020 12:50:06.490 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/home/u/tomcat/webapps/manager]
21-Aug-2020 12:50:06.578 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/u/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [87] ms
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669233/error-creating-transaction-manager-bean

Answer (score 0):

The reason was an IntelliJ issue that rebuilding artifacts was needed.
After that it worked. So the error message was not relating to the code in my question.

[image]